# How do I acces a variable in html from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

Hi I am working on a project and am using express and socketio to construct a website. When I get to index.ejs I get a variable called LocalName that I wish to use in a javascript file linked to index.ejs.

This code is used when creating the variable:

```
app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs', { LocalName: req.user.name })
})
```

This is what I wish to do with the variable:

```
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')
const message = string(LocalName) + ": " + string(messageInput.value)
```

I have tried using getelementbyBLANK but it does not work.

Comment: `LocalName` needs to be somewhere in your page. Then you could read the string from where it is in the html.

Comment: You can't access the client DOM directly on the server. The client code needs to send the input value in the AJAX call.